# Is there any difference in meaning between "run around the house" and "run about the house"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Is there any difference in meaning between *run around the house* and *run about the house*? For example:

> The children **ran around** the house the whole day.
>
> The children **ran about** the house the whole day.

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Does it mean that both words can be used interchangeably?

Comment: Google Ngram indicates that "run around" has been more popular than "run about" since 1980. Before then it was reversed. So "run around" sounds more contemporary.